# Magento 2: Any Observer event trigger when product back in stock?

Tags: event-observer, out-of-stock, magento2.4, stock-alert

Hi guys I am looking for an observer event which triggered when product back in stock.
So I do not know which Magento 2 event I have to be called when product back is in stock.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, back in stock is done from the admin side,

So you can use this event :

```
catalog_product_save_after
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in Magento we have event for stock save.

Event name is : **cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after**

If this helps then hit like.

Enjoy your coding !!! :)

Thank you
Hiren Pate